# HTML picture link failure

Tags: html, outlook

I am pasting several pics in a html file, called myhtml.html. I added these pics in this way:

```
<div class="container">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <img src="Round 36.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
          <hr>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <img src="Round 36.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
          <hr>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Then I want to send this as an attachment through Outlook.

However when I sent them out the links broke and no pics were shown.

Is there any method to "fixate" these pics? I'm also thinking of transforming the html into pdf but it is for me a big work as I have no idea how this transformation takes place in Python.

Thanks!

Comment: ummm.... what does this have to do with Python, PDF generation, or Spyder?

Comment: The generation of this html file is done in Python and final email is sent through Python..